# Can a oracle function return more than one value

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, parameters, procedures

I have a confusion regarding the OUT parameter and RETURN type of a function in oracle PL SQL. I have few questions regarding this.

1. Can someone please explain the difference between the two?
2. Can a function have both IN and OUT parameter like a procedure?
3. Is it possible to return more than one value using functions?

I have searched over the internet but I am getting different answers which are confusing me further.

Comment: one return, you can mix `in`, `out` and `in out` as you want.

Comment: You can create a `TYPE` with multiple members and return that type

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Kevin

Answer (score 1):

1) If function have only `IN` parameters than you can use that function in queries.

```
create or replace function my_func( i in integer) 
return integer as
begin
    return i+1; 
end;

select my_func(1) from dual;
```

2) Yes. In functions are allowed using `IN` and `OUT` parameters.

```
 create or replace function  my_func( i in integer, j out integer, k in out integer) return integer as
 begin
    j:= i + 2; 
    k:= k + i;
    return i+1;
 end;
```

3) Yes, you can use many `OUT` parameters, but only one `RETURN`

```
 create or replace function my_func( i in integer, j out integer, k out integer) 
 return integer as
 begin
    j:= i + 2; 
    k:= i + 3;
    return i+1;
 end;
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I have executed the code given for my 3rd questions and I have understood what happens if we give more than one out parameter in functions.

Comment: I have another request, in many places it was mentioned that it is not advisable to use OUT parameter in a function and it is better to use a procedure in such a scenario. What is the difference. Can you please explain me why a procedure with OUT parameter is better than a function? ... Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it is mean that your code will be more clear if you will not mixing `return` and `out` parameters in functions. If you need return only one value, then  function  it is a better way. If you need to use many `out` parametrs, then use procedures with `out` parameters.  But in PL/SQL  we don't have any restriction for using `out ` parameters in functions.

Answer (score 0):

3. If you want to return more than one value from function you can return previously defined user type that contains many fields. However this is a bit dirty solution.